# how to confirm that by react-native-code-push, the app downloads the package in the wifi condition?

Tags: react-native

is react-native-code-push providing a config to confirm that the package is downloaded only in a wifi condition?
otherwise,the end-user has to download the package in other network condition(3G/4G .etc),and maybe they don't konw about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#content) API and register a callback with `addEventListener` on a `change` event. Trigger CodePush `sync` only incase of `wifi`.